# Message queue for push notification/mail application?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

I need a message queue where I can order messages PER USER and there will be multiple consumers and each consumer can take any message not being processed by another consumer. A consumer may take a while to process a message (it may have to send out a push notification say). Because of this, I can't use Kafka partitions since we can't get to messages past the first one if two users share the partition. E.g.,

user2Message_10 user1Message_40 user1Message_39 (39 is being processed by a consumer and Kafka won't let us see user2's message because the front message user1Message_39 is still being processed)

What I really need is a queue per user and if there are no messages for the user the queue is deleted since we'll recreate it when a message for that user shows up. Messages per user MUST go in order. The unprocessed messages must be durable but if a message is processed, we don't need to remember it anymore. Are there any systems like this that are high volume?

It seems like I need something like direct exchange routing or topic exchange routing but I don't need the historical part of the queue since I can forget it when the consumer has succcessfully processed it. A consumer can also fail to send a message and if so it is just puts the message on the front of the queue again for another consumer (perhaps with a retry count eventually ending up in DLQ). Consumers can only process a single message at a time and other consumers can't get messages from that user's queue if another consumer is processing the front of it.

I don't think any of the message queueing systems fits this need as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

##### RabbitMQ works for this. Use a direct exchange where the queue name is the username.

> The unprocessed messages must be durable but if a message is processed, we don't need to remember it anymore.

Set `durable = true` on the queue, and set `persistent = true` on the messages. They will be saved to disk in case of server restart (but it won't keep messages after they are processed).

> the queue is deleted since we'll recreate it when a message for that user shows up.

Since you want your queue to be durable, it won't make sense to also make it an auto-delete queue. What you can do is [set expiration on the queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#queue-ttl) which causes it to be deleted after not being used for the configured amount of time. However, it would be worth just trying it without the expiration, since there might not be any performance problem.

> Consumers can only process a single message at a time and other consumers can't get messages from that user's queue if another consumer is processing the front of it.

Enable [Single Active Consumer](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#single-active-consumer) on the queues. This will ensure that messages are processed in order, since only one messages gets processed at a time.

> A consumer can also fail to send a message and if so it is just puts the message on the front of the queue again

Use [manual acknowledgements](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#acknowledgement-modes) so that if the consumer fails to send the message, it can send a negative acknowledgement to the queue to have the message requeued at the head of the queue.

Comment: That's great! Thanks! I assume I'd also need timeouts if the consumer dies and never processes the messsages. These timeouts could be short if the consumer was required to "keepalive" back to the broker saying "still processing!". If you don't hear these, you could time out sooner.

Comment: The auto-delete functionality isn't exactly what I want but it may work. Auto-delete seems to delete the queue even if there are messages in it. I don't want that. However, if I put a long timeout on the auto-delete it is likely that the queue will be read by a free consumer before some time constraint (say a week). If all your consumers are dead for a week you have a bigger problem.

Comment: For the single active consumer model, it is likely I'd have WAY MORE queues than consumers so the consumers would have share the queues. These queues would be created (and probably deleted) many times per second as there isn't much queue locality (maybe a few messages per queue but most queues different).

Comment: Regarding your first comment about timeouts - the manual acknowledgements handle this because if the consumer has not sent an acknowledgement back to the queue (either a positive or negative acknowledgement) the message will be re-queued. The time limit on that is configurable, as well as what happens to the message when that occurs.